# как совместить и градиент на тексте и тень за текстом

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
h1 {
  font-family: ben-krush;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-shadow: 3px 1px 2px rgba(76, 104, 119, 0);
  -webkit-background-clip: text !important;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(51deg, #ff0000 14%, #09bef3 19%);
}
```

```html
<h1>Акция!</h1>
```

Если использовать отдельно градиент - градиент отображается.
При применении тени `text-shadow` - тень закрывает сверху сам градиент сплошным цветом тени.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас есть возможность использовать position: absolute, то можно добавить ещё 1 такую же надпись, задать обеим position: absolute, раскидать z-index, чтобы одна надпись была строго под другой и первой сделать градиент, а второй тень, у которой z-index меньше..

стили для H1:

```
h1 {
   postion: absolute;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
   z-index: 1;
   text-shadow: 3px 1px 2px rgb(76, 104, 119);
}
```

[Акция](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j96Tc.png)][image: стиль_2][image: общие стили]

Comment: Пожалуйста, используйте вставку кода как текста, а не изображений.

Comment: @Alexey Zolotov - спасибо за решение